# 'requests.get' Why can't I get the correct response?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I test api by CURL tool.I get correct response.But function 'requests.get' not get .

This is my curl

```
curl 'https://xyq.cbg.163.com/equip?s=352&eid=201809300000113-352-DCEBW3UFAURC&view_loc=equip_list' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: https://xyq.cbg.163.com/cgi-bin/login.py?next_url=%2Fequip%3Fs%3D352%26eid%3D201809300000113-352-DCEBW3UFAURC%26view_loc%3Dequip_list&server_id=352&act=do_anon_auth' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,und;q=0.7' -H 'Cookie: vjuids=5568da96a.1645fa80ea3.0.9bce666ccd158; vjlast=1530613207.1530613207.30; _ntes_nnid=6225af57f6bccb13029779bc5f612dc1,1530613206698; _ntes_nuid=6225af57f6bccb13029779bc5f612dc1; P_INFO=jiangwei1995910@163.com|1538213634|0|mail163|11&10|bej&1538141485&xyq#bej&null#10#0#0|&0|xyq&cbg|jiangwei1995910@163.com; nts_mail_user=jiangwei1995910@163.com:-1:1; mail_psc_fingerprint=bfb14236794fea1c71128deb46355f02; usertrack=CrH3/luvRwWoRWDVAx0mAg==; area_id=52; __session__=1; fingerprint=1264686547; cur_servername=%25E5%25BE%25B7%25E9%2598%25B3%25E6%2596%2587%25E5%25BA%2599; sid=smTmSs6c2gPxqlDfsmXuUsNNJPcba_CNNrv7uvbJ; last_login_serverid=352; wallet_data=%7B%22is_locked%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22checking_balance%22%3A%200%2C%20%22balance%22%3A%200%2C%20%22free_balance%22%3A%200%7D; latest_views=159_2928104-275_1957182-167_1244727-123_2368954-167_1178024-167_1232781-167_1244661-167_1243011-167_1245563-123_2327135-221_1481157-829_181405-173_3263018-352_2811234' --compressed
```

And this is my code:

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://xyq.cbg.163.com/equip?s=352&eid=201809300000113-352-DCEBW3UFAURC&view_loc=equip_list")
headers={
'Host': 'xyq.cbg.163.com',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'Referer': 'https://xyq.cbg.163.com/cgi-bin/login.py?next_url=%2Fequip%3Fs%3D352%26eid%3D201809300000113-352-DCEBW3UFAURC%26view_loc%3Dequip_list&server_id=352&act=do_anon_auth',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,und;q=0.7',
'Cookie': 'vjuids=5568da96a.1645fa80ea3.0.9bce666ccd158; vjlast=1530613207.1530613207.30; _ntes_nnid=6225af57f6bccb13029779bc5f612dc1,1530613206698; _ntes_nuid=6225af57f6bccb13029779bc5f612dc1; P_INFO=jiangwei1995910@163.com|1538213634|0|mail163|11&10|bej&1538141485&xyq#bej&null#10#0#0|&0|xyq&cbg|jiangwei1995910@163.com; nts_mail_user=jiangwei1995910@163.com:-1:1; mail_psc_fingerprint=bfb14236794fea1c71128deb46355f02; usertrack=CrH3/luvRwWoRWDVAx0mAg==; area_id=52; __session__=1; fingerprint=1264686547; cur_servername=%25E5%25BE%25B7%25E9%2598%25B3%25E6%2596%2587%25E5%25BA%2599; sid=smTmSs6c2gPxqlDfsmXuUsNNJPcba_CNNrv7uvbJ; last_login_serverid=352; wallet_data=%7B%22is_locked%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22checking_balance%22%3A%200%2C%20%22balance%22%3A%200%2C%20%22free_balance%22%3A%200%7D; latest_views=159_2928104-275_1957182-167_1244727-123_2368954-167_1178024-167_1232781-167_1244661-167_1243011-167_1245563-123_2327135-221_1481157-829_181405-173_3263018-352_2811234'
}
res.encoding='gb2312'
print(res.text)
```

Why i get different response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the headers dictionary but not using it for the request. You should pass it to the `get` function through the `headers` named parameter

```
res=requests.get(your_url, headers=headers)
```